# How do I convert AAC to FLAC and downsize s32le to s16le while keeping media tags?

Tags: linux, files, audio, conversion

I'm struggling with this and cannot figure out how to do that: I have a couple of audio files, *.m4a encoded with AAC, 32 bits per sample, which I'd like to convert to FLAC, 16 bits per sample, highest compression. I'd also like to keep the original media tags in the process.

I'm not looking for a GUI solution, only a command line solution. 
Can I do that with ffmpeg?

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but [this script](https://gist.github.com/lcd047/a5533dd4299ccc8e20009c6bc3be50b3) Works For Me (TM).

Comment: Thanks @lcd047 . So I guess it's not possible to do transcoding from AAC and downsampling and keeping meta tags with one single command line utility, right?